# Why aren't my Surefire configurationParameters being applied to tests?

Tags: maven, junit, pom.xml, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to apply JUnit configurationParamters via the pom through Surefire, version 3.0.0-M3.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <configuration>
        <properties>
            <configurationParameters>
                junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled=true
                junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default=concurrent
                junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.strategy=dynamic
                junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.dynamic.factor=${junit.parallel.dynamic.factor}
            </configurationParameters>
        </properties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

These configuration paramters were previously set inside the junit.properties file and worked when ran via the command line `mvn clean verify`. I am trying to make the dynamic factor variable configurable via using profiles in the pom and overide the junit.properties file per the [JUnit5 documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-config-params).

Having tried both running the build with and without the junit.properties file, the new configuration parameters set under surefire don't seem to be applied with the tests reverting to either the junit.properties settings or when that's removed, default settings.

The tests in question have a `@SpringBootTest` annotation at the top of each test class.

Project is built using SpringBoot 2.6.3 and uses the starter test dependency, this comes with JUnit 5.8.3 to my knowledge and this appears under my external libraries in IntelliJ:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I put in invalid configuartionParamters in the pom I do get errors so I know they are being set somewhere but they aren't being applied to the tests during the build/runtime.

I tried configururing JUnit configuration parameters via the Surefire plugin within the POM.

These are not being applied to my tests during run time/mvn build. However when done through the junit.properties file it works fine.

Comment: First upgrade to most recent version of maven-surefire-plugin (3.0.0) and recheck

Comment: Agree with @khmarbaise. Even the example in the [JUnit 5 docs](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven-config-params) shows using 3.0.0-M7 of the Surefire plugin.

Comment: Also try first to remove the properties which has been set in your configuration...first try with literal values...also show the whole pom file...